# Change Add new Item Text

Tags: list, visual-studio, list-definition

I've developed a ListTemplate via ListDefinition in SP 2010 using Visual Studio. Nearly everything works fine, but the Link at the bottom of my ListInstance is missing the Text "Add new Item". Is there a simple solution to change this text. I guess it would be found in a subarea of the View-tag... this would be my prefered solution. Maybe in the Toolbar- or the XSL- region? Here is my view:

```
  <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
    <Toolbar Type="Standard"> </Toolbar>
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="TeamSite"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="PublicInformations"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="ProjectManager"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="ProjectStartDate"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="ProjectEndDate"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="TimeRecordingNumber"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="ProjectSize"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="ProjectState"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="TRUE"></FieldRef>
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake... The BaseViewId was 0. After I changed it to 1, the link under the View is correct. "Add new Item"
fyi:

```
  <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" TargetType="List" DefaultViewForContentType="TRUE" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png"  Url="AllItems.aspx">
```

I found the reason in the main.xsl. it imports the vwstyles.xsl which define the behavior of rendering. In the vwstyles.xsl is written:

```
<!-- BaseViewID = 0 is summary view (home page view)-->
<xsl:template name="View_DefaultSummary_RootTemplate" mode="RootTemplate" match="View[@BaseViewID='0']" ddwrt:dvt_mode="root">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="full" />
</xsl:template>
```

So...this was the cause of my failure. The templates and also the link below the ListView won't be applied to View with BaseViewId!=0